# String prints specific number of words in to a new Line

Tags: java

I wonder how can I change my code so, that the number of given value words was specified in another class. And in construction class I need to make a method that prints in every given value. Here is my code:

```
public void wordBox()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++)
        {
        if (words.length() % wordsPerLine == 0 && words.charAt(wordsPerLine) == ' ')
            System.out.println();               
        else 
            System.out.print(words.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

wordsPerLine was given in another class as a number of 3.
String is this:"the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"

output should be look like:

the quick brown

fox jumped over

the lazy dog

Note: I am not allowed to use any other classes like token or buffer. Also, I cannot use replace/split. So, this is what I was given and I need to work from that.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: @Asaf the homework tag has been deprecated

Comment: @Bohemian, thanks for the update. I removed the homework tag appropriately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than making `words` and `wordsPerLine` instance variables that are set in the constructor, make them parameters passed to your static method, like this:

```
public static void wordBox(String words, int wordsPerLine) {
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++)
    {
    if (words.charAt(i) == ' ' && (count++) % wordsPerLine == 0)
        System.out.println();               
    else 
        System.out.print(words.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This way you would be able to specify `words` and `wordsPerLine` independently of the constructor, and call `wordBox` from anywhere with any combination of words and the desired number of words per line.

Here is a [link to ideone with this running program](http://ideone.com/clone/9KAJ0Z).

Comment: @user1780039 Take a look at the edit, I changed your code a little and added a link to ideone so that you could further modify and play with it.

Comment: oh, thanks. So, I was right most of the time. I just need to have an extra variable, set that into 1, and instead of calling words.length() == wordsPerLine == 0, I need to put that thing. awesome. thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1780039 You are welcome! If the code works for you, you may want to accept the answer to indicate to others that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution, and to earn yourself a brand-new badge on Stack Overflow.